# Show app name next to the icon in news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When I post is published using the application on facebook, there is a small icon below, next to the like button. I want to add application name or some custom text right next to that icon. Below is a screenshot of twitter app that does what I mean. Posts are published using open graph api. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called actions, and you can add them by sending an array of JSON objects as a parameter to your post call.

Example:

```
actions=[{'name':'@JemalaTony on Twitter', 'link':'http://twitter.com/#!/JemalaTony'}]
```

Source: [Graph API > Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: The problem in my case is that I don't use standard post object when publishing actions using the open graph. In this case the publishing flow is somehow different.

Comment: Then you can't do that, that's a feature of Feed stories, not Open Graph actions, Open Graph actions have action links, but they work differently

Comment: How are you posting to the open graph then?